# dynamic linq query with or and like

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Let's suppose i have a list which contains strings. This list size is not known at compilation time.

```
List<String> liste = new List<String>
liste.Add("value1");
liste.Add("value2");
liste.Add("value3");
```

There is the SQL query i want to write:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE myfield LIKE '%value1%'
   OR myfield LIKE '%value2%' 
   OR myfield LIKE '%value3%'
```

Here is what i wrote with Entity Framework and linq:

```
dbcontext.MyTable.Where(r => r. myfield.Contains(liste[0]) || r. myfield.Contains(liste[1]) || r. myfield.Contains(liste[2]));
```

My question is how can i iterate because my list wont contains 3 elements...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like below in your code

```
var res = dbcontext.MyTable.Where(r => liste.Any(val=>val == r.myfield));
```

Comment: That LINQ query is not equivalent to SQL query provided by Bob5421.